# How do i make visual studio code use my ramdisk in /mnt/ramdisk

Tags: linux, optimization, debian, visual-studio-code

I want it to optimize my system performance using ramdisk
which is created in `/mnt/ramdisk` how do I point the vs code cache to make it use the ramdisk?

I have checked the Vs Code built-in settings but I do not see anything that solves the current issue.

I don't want it to use my `/home` directory.

any help from the community or how to go about it?.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code supports [portable mode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/docs/editor/portable.md). In this mode all data created and maintained by VS Code live near itself. You can symlink the `data` folder to a folder in your `/mnt/ramdisk`.

Comment: so I copy all vs code files to a file data dir and symlink the cache because my /mnt/ramdisk is sort of temporary. do i need to download the portable version of vs code to do this?

Comment: yes, "Portable mode is supported on the ZIP download for Windows, and the TAR.GZ download for Linux..".

Comment: This is a disingenious suggestion as portable mode will lump together _all_ data -- cache-able and persistent, stateful data. This means that the user will lose all their VSCode related data when powering off.